# python-spidermonkey object has no attribute 'eval_script' error

Tags: python, spidermonkey

Using python-spidermonkey in the following way (following the [guide](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/#Tutorial)) gives me the error `AttributeError: 'spidermonkey.Context' object has not attribute 'eval_script'`.

```
>>> import spidermonkey
>>> rt = spidermonkey.Runtime()
>>> cx = rt.new_context()
>>> cx.eval_script("1 + 2") + 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'spidermonkey.Context' object has no attribute 'eval_script'
```

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and I have also found this bug report:
https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/security/+build/3866138

Installing this package on Ubuntu (12.10) worked for me:
https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/security/+build/3866138